# ANTRL4 grammar analysis rule

Tags: antlr4

Recently,I learning ANTRL4, but I can't understand why "..." is not match ID lexical rule?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when you add a literal token in your grammar, like `'...'`, this `'...'` token is converted into a real lexer rule.

For example, if your grammar looks like this:

```
grammar T;

parse : '...';
ID    : '.'+;
```

ANTLR will treat is as the following grammar:

```
grammar T;

parse : T__1;
T__1  : '...';
ID    : '.'+;
```

And because of that, input like `"..."` will always be tokenised as a `T__1` token and not as a `ID` token.

ANTLR's lexer works following 2 easy rules:

1. try to match the rule that consumes the most characters
2. if 2 (or more) rules match the same characters, let the rule defined first "win"

That is why `"..."` becomes a `T__1` token (rule 2 applies), and input like `"...."` becomes a `ID` token (rule 1 applies).

And I couldn't agree more with Mike's comment:

> Additional note: because of this and similar problems it's strongly advised to use only explicit lexer rules, not implicit ones like that `'...'` in the parser grammar.

Comment: Additional note: because of this and similar problems it's strongly advised to use only explicit lexer rules, not implicit ones like that `...` in the parser grammar.